# How to create an Expression Parser with Tree using Struct

Tags: c, parsing, tree, expression

I have a problem I do not understand. I want to create an Expression Parser. So, first I created a tree for that parser. And this is it.

```c
enum {
    integer, plus, minus, multi, divis, string, character
};

struct Tree {
    int operation;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
    char *value;
};

struct Tree *make_node(int operation, struct Tree *left, struct Tree *right, char *value) {
    struct Tree *n;
    
    n = (struct Tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
    
    if(n == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to malloc \'make_node()\'\n");
    }
    
    n -> operation = operation;
    n -> left = left;
    n -> right = right;
    n -> value = value;
    
    return n;
}

// Print ostorder
int print_post_order_data(struct Tree *n) {
    if(n == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    print_post_order_data(n -> left);   
    print_post_order_data(n -> right);
    
    printf("Operation => %d \t Value => %s\n", n -> operation, n -> value);
}

int main(void) {
    struct Tree *m;
    
    // Expression is ( 2 + 3 * 5 - 8 / 3 )
    m = make_node(plus, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> left = make_node(minus, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "2");
    m -> left -> left = make_node(multi, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> left -> right = make_node(divis, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> left -> left -> left = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "3");
    m -> left -> left -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "5");
    m -> left -> right -> left = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "8");
    m -> left -> right -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "3");

    print_post_order_data(n);

    return 0;
}
```

You can see that I have created the tree manually for expression. Expression is **2 + 3 * 5 - 8 / 3**.

Suppose that, this program can identify **2** as a Number, **+** as a plus mark etc. How do I write a parser for this. That is, to create a nodes as described above? Can to tell me the **code** or **pseudo** code for this?

Below is More Information

```c
e.g. => 1 + 2 * 3

The tree is,
                +
               / \
              /   \
             *     1
            / \
           /   \
          2     3

1 + 2 * 3 => 1 + ( 2 * 3 )

So manually I can create tree like this.

    struct Tree *n;
    n = make_node(plus, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    n -> left = make_node(multi, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    n -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "1");
    n -> left -> left = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "2");
    n -> left -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "3");
```

I tried to create a parser like this.

```c
addictive_expression() {
    multiplicative_expression()

    while(1) {
        multiplicative_expression()

        ....
    }
}


multiplicative_expression() {
    primary_expression()

    while(+ || * || /) {
        primary_expression()

        ....
    }
}

primary_expression() {
    switch(current token) {
        case integer:
             ....
             ....
    }
}
```

Although I tried to make it this way, But I'm hard to figure out how to connect the tree to it.

**EDIT 1**

1. I want to create a parser without using tools like Bison etc.
2. The lexer required for this has been made

**Edit 2 :**

```
// This is the Source of Struct Tree
struct TREE {
        int operation;
        struct TREE *left;
        struct TREE *right;
        char *value;
} Tree;

struct TREE *create_new_node(int operation, struct TREE *left, struct TREE *right, char value[MAX_LENG]) {
        struct TREE *n;

        n = (struct TREE *) malloc (sizeof(struct TREE));

        if(n == NULL) {
                fatal("Unable to Malloc New Structure TREE in \'create_new_node()\' Function in tree.c File");
        }

        n -> operation = operation;
        n -> left = left;
        n -> right = right;
        n -> value = value;

        return n;
}

// This is the Source of Parser
int expression(void) {
        next_token(); // This Function will get the next Token

        addictive_expression();
}

int addictive_expression(void) {
        int token_type;

        multiplicative_expression();

        token_type = Token.current_token; // Token.current_token is the Current Token
        if(token_type == END_FILE) {
                return 0;
        }

        while(1) {
                next_token();

                multiplicative_expression();
                
                token_type = Token.current_token;
                if(token_type == END_FILE) { // End File is a Enum
                        return 0;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}

int multiplicative_expression(void) {
        int token_type;

        primary_expression();

        token_type = Token.current_token;
        if(token_type == END_FILE) {
                return 0;
        }

        // O_MLTI, O_DIVS. O_MUDL are the tokens ( Enum )
        while(token_type == O_MLTI || token_type == O_DIVS || token_type == O_MUDL) {
                next_token();

                primary_expression();

                token_type = Token.current_token;
                if(token_type == END_FILE) {
                        return 0;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}

int primary_expression(void) {
        switch(Token.current_token) {
                case INTEGER:
                        next_token();
                        break;
                
                case O_PLUS:
                case O_MNUS:
                case O_MLTI:
                case O_DIVS:
                case O_MUDL:
                        next_token();
                        break;
                
                default:
                        error_d("Syntax Error in Primary Expression", Token.current_token); // Custom Error Message
                        break;
        }

        return 0;
}

/*
    struct Tree *m;

    m = make_node(plus, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> left = make_node(minus, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "2");
    m -> left -> left = make_node(multi, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> left -> right = make_node(divis, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    m -> left -> left -> left = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "3");
    m -> left -> left -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "5");
    m -> left -> right -> left = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "8");
    m -> left -> right -> right = make_node(integer, NULL, NULL, "3");
*/
```

**I'm hard to figure out how to connect the tree to it.** Can you give me a solution for that?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to first use Lex/Flex and Yacc/Bison and see their tutorials :D

Comment: Or even read this [first chapter](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/ch01.html) of the Flex-Bison book from O'Reilly

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you. But I don't like to use Flex, Bison or other generation tool. Sorry about that ! I will include it in the function :)

Comment: I mean, if you've not *ever* written the parser, or lexer, then you should definitely try them first... that way you will have much less to figure first... then you can throw bison, flex generated code away later if you feel so

Comment: If you just need a simple expression parser, then all you need is (1) to identify the tokens, and (2) a simple recursive-descent parser.  Creating a token stream is pretty simple, and you can google recursive descent parsers.

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes I made a simple lexer for this. The problem I have here is how to write the parser so that the **tree** is created

Comment: For simple expression parsing, [Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is a relatively simple and straightforward algorithm to implement. For something more elaborate, you may want to look up how to build an LR parser or a packrat parser.

Comment: @TomKarzes They were all done. Also the parser is finished. But I does not make sense to create a tree through the prser :/

Comment: @LasanNishshanka A tree is the natural result of parsing.  When you parse a `+` operator, you parse the left and right operands (as trees), then create a new node for the `+` operator, using the two sub-trees as its left and right operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonterminals of the grammar are implemented by functions that are returning itself a sub-expression, in your case represented by a `struct Tree *`.

This allows the construction of a tree when called recursively.

So basically your `addictive_expression` should rather look like this:

```
static struct Tree *addictive_expression() {
    struct Tree *expr = multiplicative_expression();
    while (token->type == OPERATOR && (token->op == PLUS || token->op == MINUS)) {
        Operator op = token->op;
        token = next_token();
        struct Tree *expr2 = multiplicative_expression();
        switch (op) {
            case PLUS:
                expr = create_new_node(OPERATOR, PLUS, expr, expr2, NULL);
                break;
            case MINUS:
                expr = create_new_node(OPERATOR, MINUS, expr, expr2, NULL);
                break;
        }
    }
    return expr;
}
```

How does it work:

It calls `multiplicative_expression`, which in turn calls other functions to get an expression. In a simple form of recursive-descending parsing, you have a separate function for each precedence level. Since PLUS and MINUS are left-associative operators, they are processed in a loop. If there are successive operations of the same precedence level, the previous node is set as left expression when the new node is created.

For a better understanding I have added there a switch statement with PLUS and MINUS cases, but as you can see, you can simplify it to:

```
static struct Tree *multiplicative_expression() {
    struct Tree *expr = value_expression();
    while (token->type == OPERATOR && (token->op == MULT || token->op == DIV)) {
        Operator op = token->op;
        token = next_token();
        struct Tree *expr2 = value_expression();
        expr = create_new_node(OPERATOR, op, expr, expr2, NULL);
    }
    return expr;
}
```

Here just the operator is used to create a new node.

**Data Structures**

Note: Type and Operator are separated.

```
typedef enum  {
    NONE,
    END,
    NUMERIC,
    OPERATOR
} Type;

typedef enum {
    INVALID,
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MULT,
    DIV
} Operator;

typedef struct {
    Type type;
    Operator op;
    char *value;
} Token;
```

The tree struct is then:

```
struct Tree {
    Type type;
    Operator op;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
    char *value;
};
```

**Complete Example**

So a small but complete example, where function names are based on the example snippets in the question, could look something like this with two precedence levels:

- `*` and `/`
- `+` and `-`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"
#include "lexer.h"

static Token *token;

static void fatal(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

static struct Tree *create_new_node(Type type,
                                    Operator operation,
                                    struct Tree *left,
                                    struct Tree *right,
                                    char *value) {
    struct Tree *n = (struct Tree*) malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
    if (n == NULL) {
        fatal("Unable to Malloc New Structure Tree in \'create_new_node()\' Function in tree.c File");
    }
    n->type = type;
    n->op = operation;
    n->left = left;
    n->right = right;
    n->value = value;
    return n;
}


static struct Tree *value_expression() {
    if (token->type == NUMERIC) {
        struct Tree *result = create_new_node(NUMERIC, NONE, NULL, NULL, strdup(token->value));
        token = next_token();
        return result;
    }
    fatal("can't determine value for token");
}

static struct Tree *multiplicative_expression() {
    struct Tree *expr = value_expression();
    while (token->type == OPERATOR && (token->op == MULT || token->op == DIV)) {
        Operator op = token->op;
        token = next_token();
        struct Tree *expr2 = value_expression();
        expr = create_new_node(OPERATOR, op, expr, expr2, NULL);
    }
    return expr;
}

static struct Tree *addictive_expression() {
    struct Tree *expr = multiplicative_expression();
    while (token->type == OPERATOR && (token->op == PLUS || token->op == MINUS)) {
        Operator op = token->op;
        token = next_token();
        struct Tree *expr2 = multiplicative_expression();
        expr = create_new_node(OPERATOR, op, expr, expr2, NULL);
    }
    return expr;
}

struct Tree *expression() {
    token = next_token();
    struct Tree *expr = addictive_expression();
    putback_token(token);
    return expr;
}
```

**Tree Output**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lexer.h"
#include "parser.h"

void test_parser();

int main(void) {
    test_parser();
    return 0;
}

void print_expr(struct Tree *expr, int level) {
    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        printf("  |  ");
    }
    switch(expr->type) {
        case OPERATOR:
            switch(expr->op) {
                case INVALID:
                    fprintf(stderr, "invalid op\n");
                    exit(1);
                case PLUS:
                    printf("+\n");
                    print_expr(expr->left, level + 1);
                    print_expr(expr->right, level + 1);
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
                case MINUS:
                    printf("-\n");
                    print_expr(expr->left, level + 1);
                    print_expr(expr->right, level + 1);
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
                case MULT:
                    printf("*\n");
                    print_expr(expr->left, level + 1);
                    print_expr(expr->right, level + 1);
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
                case DIV:
                    printf("/\n");
                    print_expr(expr->left, level + 1);
                    print_expr(expr->right, level + 1);
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            printf("%s\n", expr->value);
            break;
        case NONE:
            fprintf(stderr, "unexpected NONE\n");
            exit(1);
        case END:
            fprintf(stderr, "unexpected END\n");
            exit(1);
    }
}

void test_parser() {
    setup_lexer("../input.txt");
    struct Tree *expr = expression();
    print_expr(expr, 0);
}
```

**Result**

For the input `2 + 3 * 5 - 8 / 3` the small test program above outputs the following to the debug console:

```
-
  |  +
  |    |  2
  |    |  *
  |    |    |  3
  |    |    |  5


  |  /
  |    |  8
  |    |  3
```

which looks like the correct syntax tree!

Comment: Thank you very much. You have explained the answer **very clearly**.